# tikz diamond node white space

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wonder how I can remove the white space between the diamond node and the link in the following MWE.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=0.2in, includefoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec,lipsum}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setromanfont{Century Gothic}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{font=\Large,
every node/.style=
    {rectangle,rounded corners,
    draw=black,
    very thick,
    align=center
    }}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
\node (a) {AAAAA};
\node[diamond, below=of a] (R) {BBBBB};
\node[below right=of R](d){CCCCC};
\draw[->][ultra thick](R.east) -| node[above, draw=none,near start,yshift=0.1cm] {No} (d.north);
\draw[->][ultra thick](a.south) -- (R.north);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rounded corners modify the what it should have been a sharp corner path but not moving the anchors accordingly. A quick fix is to add `shorten <` and `shorten >` keys to nudge the start/end points of the paths

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=0.2in, includefoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec,lipsum}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setromanfont{Century Gothic}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{font=\Large,
every node/.style=
    {rectangle,rounded corners,
    draw=black,
    very thick,
    align=center
    }}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
\node (a) {AAAAA};
\node[diamond, below=of a] (R) {BBBBB};
\node[below right=of R](d){CCCCC};
\draw[->,shorten <=-2pt][ultra thick](R.east) -| node[above, draw=none,near start,yshift=0.1cm] {No} (d.north);
\draw[->,shorten >=-2pt][ultra thick](a.south) -- (R.north);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]